# How to properly fix 'This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled.' in Unity 2019

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, arcore

I have an error after implementing Google Play games in Unity 2019, I'm using Google ARcore and Google Play games for Android. I never had a problem with this before and I read through some answers online on forums, but they all not work.
Does someone know how to fix this error?
I already have tried to change the mainTemplate.gradle file but it doesn't work.

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.
This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```